# Classes using other classes/methods

Tags: c#

I made a program that essentially contained 150 actions, all in the first form. It has become a nightmare to manage and a friend recommended splitting groups of actions into separate classes.
Ideally going from: `Do {1,2,3,4,5}` to `Do {A,B}` where `A` is `{1,2,3}` and `B` is `{4,5}`.

To practice, I decided to try to work 2 classes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            checkTrue();
        }
        else
        {
            checkFalse();
        }
    }

    public void checkTrue()
    {
        textBox.Text = "checkbox was checked";
    }

    public void checkFalse()
    {
        textBox.Text = "unchecked :(";
    }
}
```

How would I go about changing this to a set it as a new class to be called upon?
When creating a new class "checkBool", I wrote the following in a new .cs:

```
class checkBool
{
    public void checkTrue()
    {
        textBox.Text = "checkbox was checked";
    }

    public void checkFalse()
    {
        textBox.Text = "unchecked :(";
    }
}
```

However, the textbox is no longer recognized. How can I make this new class understand the reference?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `textbox` is not recognized by the `checkbool` instance because it doesn't know about it.

One quick way to "let it know about it" is passing the `textbox` as a parameter to the `checkTrue()` and `checkFalse()` operations, like this:

```
class checkBool
{
    public void checkTrue(TextBox textBox)
    {
        textBox.Text = "checkbox was checked";
    }
    public void checkFalse(TextBox textbox)
    {
        textBox.Text = "unchecked :(";
    }
}
```

So the button click handler would be:

```
public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    checkBool cb = new checkBool();
    if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)
    {
        cb.checkTrue(textbox);
    }
    else
    {
        cb.checkFalse(textbox);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that by doing this you are introducing a dependency to your class `checkBool` (It depends to `TextBox` now).

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question fully.
I am not sure why having a dependency is bad (or so I get the feeling from the answers) but it does resolve my question. :)

Comment: Its not that they are bad per se, its just that you want to keep them at a minimum. As your projects became bigger and more complex, you will need to modify parts, and move thing around. Keeping dependencies to a minimum makes that easier, among other things.

Comment: Again, why instantiate `checkBool` if it won't have any data on its own? This a bad practice. Make `checkBool` static if it will only have helper methods.

Comment: I wasn't trying to provide a best practice solution, I was trying to answer Phils question as to why in his particular case his `checkBool` class didn't have visibility over the `Textbox`. I agree with you that a static class would be a better solution.

Comment: This is exactly the same as my answer! Good solution 

Comment: @Ric, no, it's not even close to your answer.

Comment: Lol @CamiloTerevinto don’t worry about it. All you need to do is read what I said at the end of the answer and all will be clear.